# Problems with a 'for' iteration inside a function

Tags: python

I'm trying to plot a function that have diferent behaviours, depending on the values of the x axis. For values of the x axis ('ec' variable) smaler than 2.0 it acts one way, and for values bigger than this it acts in another way.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ec = np.linspace(0., 3.,20) #range of 'x' axis values

def ten_def(x):
    for i in ec:
        if i <= 2.:
            return 0.85*x*(1-(1-(ec/2))**2) #behavior for ec < than 2.0
        else:
            return 0.85*x  #behavior for ec > 2.0

fcd = float(input('Fck (MPa): '))/1.4

plt.plot(ec, ten_def(fcd), 'b-', ec,(ec*0)+fcd*0.85,'r-')
plt.title('Tensão-deformação')
plt.xlabel('Deformação (‰)')
plt.ylabel('Tensão (MPa)')
plt.show()
```

The ploting part of the code is working. But it plots a curve that has the same behavior for the whole plot (it is considering ec<2.0 all the time). What am I doing wrong?

[image: how it is supose to be like]

Comment: The first time you return, that's the end of the function. It's like sending a messenger to someone. Once the messenger is told to go back to you with the response, any other responses are useless because the messenger is already gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must return a list of data as the output of the function.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ec = np.linspace(0., 3.,20) #range of 'x' axis values

def ten_def(x):
    result = []
    for i in ec:
        if i <= 2.:
            result.append(0.85*x*(1-(1-(i/2))**2)) #behavior for ec < than 2.0
        else:
            result.append(0.85*x)  #behavior for ec > 2.0
    return result

fcd = float(input('Fck (MPa): '))/1.4

plt.plot(ec, ten_def(fcd), 'b-')
plt.axhline(0.85*fcd, color='r')
plt.title('Tensão-deformação')
plt.xlabel('Deformação (‰)')
plt.ylabel('Tensão (MPa)')
plt.show()
```

This should give you the desired result

Comment: It gives me "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence".

Comment: @JohnEngineer try the new version. It seems as if the problem was that the whole `ec` was used in the calculation when `ec <=2` in stead of individual values.

Comment: That was exactly what I wanted! Thanks!